# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is not executing all the threads submitting to it

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I have a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor for sending emails. Currently it's corePoolSize is 5, and queueCapacity is default i.e. max value of integer (unbounded queue)

```
<bean id="emailTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
</bean>
```

The problem I am facing is few of my threads are getting executed and few are not. I have put logs to confirm the same, and comes to a conclusion that the threads are submitted to executor, but they are not even started.

**Neither** I am getting **RejectedExecutionException** exception.

What can be the reason of this?

Comment: Do the tasks you're submitting initially ever stop?

Comment: Show the code where you're submitting the tasks.

Comment: `executorService.submit(new EmailSenderTask(confirmationRequest, confirmationResponse));`

Answer (score 1):

The `Thread`s you submitted to the executor are considered as `Runnable`,only `run()`will be executed.Executor does not known it is a Thread,the Executor using internal threads to execute the tasks.So the Thread will not be `start()`,and the state also will not be changed.

Generally,when using ThreadPoolExecutor,you should wrap your task to a `Runnable`,not a `Thread`.